# Executable does not work if run outside its folder

Tags: make, executable, libraries, gnu

I have an already structured SDK folder where I have my project. Program works as expected if I do:

```
cd /home/user/Documents/Camera/ProjectCamera/linux64/proj
make
cd /home/user/Documents/Camera/ProjectCamera/linux64/lib
./Camera
```

Now I want to run the executable from outside 'lib' folder but program does not work if I do. I can run the executable but the program returns errors in some SDK functions. I want to execute this program with @reboot in crontab so I need to be able to execute this command from any folder:

```
/home/user/Documents/Camera/ProjectCamera/linux64/lib/Camera
```

I have a makefile file where some paths are already defined. I suppose this problem is related to these paths but I am not sure. I have tried modifying this file but I was not able to run the program and make it work. Here is the Makefile content:

```
#SDK测试程序

CXX   =  g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable

#包含头文件路径
SUBDIR   = $(shell ls ../../src -R | grep /)
SUBDIRS  = $(subst :,/,$(SUBDIR))
INCPATHS = $(subst ../../,-I../../,$(SUBDIRS))
INCPATHS += -I../../include/

VPATH = $(subst : ,:,$(SUBDIR))./
SOURCE = $(foreach dir,$(SUBDIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)*.cpp))

#将cpp的路径名称的.cpp后缀换为.o
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCE))
#取出.o的文件名，不带路径
OBJFILE  = $(foreach dir,$(OBJS),$(notdir $(dir)))
#.o输出到.OBJ目录下
OBJSPATH = $(addprefix obj/,$(OBJFILE)) 

LIBPATH = ../lib/
LIBS = -Wl,-rpath=./:./HCNetSDKCom:../lib -lhcnetsdk
EXE = ../lib/Camera

$(EXE):$(OBJFILE)
    $(CXX) -L$(LIBPATH)  -o $(EXE) $(OBJFILE) $(INCPATHS) $(LIBS)

$(OBJFILE):%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX)  -c -o $@ $<  $(INCPATHS) -pipe -g -Wall

#依赖文件
DPPS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.dpp,$(SOURCE))
include $(DPPS)
%.dpp: %.cpp    
    g++ $(INCPATHS) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$ 
    

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJFILE)
    rm -rf $(DPPS)
    rm -rf $(EXE)
```

I guess I have to modify this file but I need a little help because I tried without success.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to execute the command from any directory? If so, have you tried making a symbolic link to the binary(s) in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin?

Comment: What happens when you run `home/user/Documents/Camera/ProjectCamera/linux64/lib/Camera` as shown in your question?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to execute the command from any directory and I have not tried making a symbolic link. I will give it a try.

Comment: What happens is that program runs and gets stucked in the camera login function, which is the first function of the SDK in the program.

Comment: I suspect the issue may be the use of relative paths in the `-rpath` linker directive - see for example [correct usage of rpath (relative vs absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058041/correct-usage-of-rpath-relative-vs-absolute)